# How did Ramanujan come up with the Ramanujan summation and is it possible to extend it to higher number sets

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, big-list, big-picture

How did Ramanujan come up with the Ramanujan summation and is it possible to extend it to higher sets (Everything circled in red is what I'm interested in (+ the Cauchy integral to make it Dedekind completed) )

[image]

Comment: This post: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/#comment-265849 explores what is meant by "divergent summation" including Ramanujan's work

Comment: I admit that the question contains a "big picture".

Answer (score 3):

Ramanujan's reasoning is analysed in detail by Berndt, in his discussion of chapter 6 of [Ramanujan's notebooks](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-1088-7_7). Ramanujan starts from the [Euler-MacLaurin summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula),
$$\sum_{k=1}^x f(k)=C +\int_1^x f(t)\,dt+\tfrac{1}{2}f(x)+\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\frac{d^{2k-1}}{dx^{2k-1}}f(x),$$
and focuses on the constant $C$, which he uses to find the asymptotic expansion of $\sum_{k=1}^x f(k)$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. This approach was made somewhat more rigorous by Hardy.

In this way Ramanujan obtained the notorious identities $\sum 1 =-\tfrac{1}{2}$ and $\sum k = -\tfrac{1}{12}$. For a $p$-adic interpretation of the latter sum, see [this MO post.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/84663/11260)

Comment: This answer is already more than the question deserves.