# Why did Euler consider the zeta function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ho.history-overview, riemann-zeta-function, motivation

Many zeta functions and L-functions which are generalizations of the Riemann zeta function play very important roles in modern mathematics (Kummer criterion, class number formula, Weil conjecture, BSD conjecture, Langlands program, Riemann hypothesis,...).

Euler was perhaps the first person to consider the zeta function $\zeta(s)$ ($1\leq s$). Why did Euler study such a function? What was his aim?

Further, though we know their importance well, should we consider that the Riemann zeta function and its generalizations happen to play key roles in modern number theory?

Comment: I think his primary goal was to solve the so-called  Basel problem. Having managed to do so, he probably wanted to study the values of the zeta function further.

Comment: Thank you very much. Basel's casual question leads to the modern number theory!!

Comment: @Jojo Basel is a city located in Switzerland, not a person... It's Euler's hometown.

Comment: Sorry. It is Mengoli who consider the  Basel problem lol

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This history is described in [Euler and the Zeta Function](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2319041?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by Raymond Ayoub (1974). In his early twenties, around 1730, Euler considered the celebrated problem to calculate the sum $$\zeta(2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}.$$ This problem goes back to 1650, it was posed by Pietro Mengoli and John Wallis computed the sum to three decimal places. Ayoub conjectures that it was Daniel Bernoulli who drew the attention of Euler to this challenging problem. (Both lived in St. Petersburg around 1730.)

Euler first publishes several methods to compute the sum to high accuracy, arriving at $$\zeta(2)=1.64493406684822643,$$ and finally obtained $\pi^2/6$ in 1734. (We know this date from correspondence with Bernoulli.) It was published in 1735 in [De summis serierum reciprocarum](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/pages/E041.html).

[image]

<sub>$1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{25}+\frac{1}{36}+\text{etc.}=\frac{p^2}{6}$, thus the sum of this series multiplied by 6 equals the square of the circumference of a circle that has diameter 1. [*Notice that the symbol $\pi$ was not yet in use.*]</sub>

The generalization to $\zeta(s)$ with integers $s$ larger than two followed in *"De seribus quibusdam considerationes"*. In 1748, finally, Euler derives a functional equation relating the values at $s$ and $1-s$ and conjectures that it holds for any real $s$. (Euler's functional equation is equivalent to the one proven a century later by [Riemann.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Riemann%27s_functional_equation)).

Comment: Thank you very much!! By the way, though we know their importance well, we should think that the Riemann zeta functions and its generalizations happen to play key roles in the modern number theory?

Comment: @Jojo there was *no* reason to expect the central role the generalizations of $\zeta(s)$ would play in modern number theory back in the 1700s. The first time there was any generalization, to Dirichlet $L$-functions, was in the 1830s (and then only for real $s > 1$). Zeta-functions of number fields were introduced by Dedekind in the 1870s (but were only analytically continued to $\mathbf C$ by Hecke in 1917).  The central role for these constructions and more like them (for Artin representations, modular forms, etc.) was largely a 20th century realization.

Comment: What did Euler think it meant, to relate $\zeta$ at $s$ and $1-s$, given that at least one of these doesn't converge?

Comment: @DanPiponi --- for that reason Euler compared $s$ and $1-s$ for the _alternating_ zeta function $\sum_n (-1)^{n}/n^s$

Comment: We should think it is key because of [Euler’s product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Euler_product_formula) (also discussed in the Ayoub paper).

Comment: Your translation of the Latin has a small math error: you have 1/26 where it should read 1/36

Comment: @Haydentech --- typo corrected, thanks.

Comment: @DanPiponi, objecting to the lack of convergence at $s$ or $1-s$ is anachronistic. For someone like Euler in the 1700s, series were manipulated freely even if they make no sense to us. However, as Carlo says, Euler did use the alternating zeta-function (with terms $(-1)^{n-1}/n^s$, not $(-1)^n/n^s$, so it starts with $1$ at $n = 1$), which makes sense for $0 < s < 1$ but is strictly nonsense when ${\rm Re}(s) \leq 0$. My 2nd answer (not the accepted one) at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13130/historical-question-in-analytic-number-theory shows how Euler found the functional equation.

Comment: @KConrad, you can link directly to [your second answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/13417).